# Laravel cors throws error when trying to run Request::create

Tags: laravel, cors, laravel-passport

I have a custom login method for my Laravel Passport API.

I am using `Request::create` to call the /oauth/token endpoint from inside my login method.

The problem is that from within my React project, I am getting a CORS error.

The error ONLY happens when using the login method and I think I have traced it down to the way that the data is being 'returned'

I am using the `barryvdh/laravel-cors` package and the relevant portion of my login method is as follows;

```
    $data = [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 2,
        'client_secret' => 'ggdfgdvsreckuscenusekubsvbd',
        'username' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'scope' => '',
    ];

    $request = Request::create('/oauth/token', 'POST', $data);

    return app()->handle($request);
```

Is there a way that I can cast that $request response to a variable and then return it using the standard `response->json`?

If i return the $request as it is, it doesnt give me any of the data that the `return app()->handle($request);` line gives me i.e token, refresh token etc etc

I can use all other POST methods in my API except this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way. Its basically launching a new request from a another request

```php
$data = [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 2,
        'client_secret' => 'ggdfgdvsreckuscenusekubsvbd',
        'username' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
        'scope' => '',
    ];

$request = app()->make('request');
$request->request->add($data);

$tokenRequest = Request::create(
            env('APP_URL') . '/oauth/token',
            'post'
        );

return Route::dispatch($tokenRequest);
```